# Надо ли обособлять слово "главное" запятой?

Tags: пунктуация

> Впоследствии из них вырастают грамотные специалисты и главное - хорошие люди.

Верно ли расставлены знаки препинания? Или "и главное" надо как-то обособить?

Comment: @Liana Заголовок вопроса должен отражать его специфику.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

11) Слово "***главное"*** является ***вводным*** в значениях ***«особенно важно»***, «особенно существенно»: Тему для рассказа можете взять произвольную, но, главное, чтобы было интересно; Детали можно опустить, а главное — чтобы было занимательно — запятую после союза а поставить нельзя, и для усиления выделения после вводного сочетания поставлено тире; Как крупный учёный, а главное как историк искусства, он пользуется большим авторитетом — в начале обособленного оборота.[см.здесь](http://www.ngebooks.com/book_27869_chapter_32_x_x_x.html)

Впоследствии из них вырастают грамотные специалисты и, главное, хорошие люди.